# Test using enzyme and crypto-js in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme, cryptojs

I have a react app where cookies are encrypted using crypto-js. I am trying to write a unit
test (starting with a snapshot) to test the component. I am running into this error:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'salt' of undefined

      10 | 
      11 | const decryptStr = (encryptedStr) => {
    > 12 |   var bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedStr, secretKey);
         |                            ^
      13 |   var originalText = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
      14 |   return originalText;
      15 | };
```

it is trying to decrypt a cookie to be used in the component. Here is a copy of my test:

```
test('should match snapchot', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<component data={data} />);
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
})
```

The react component is simple, just maps over the provided data and renders multiple items for a list.
the cookie is a user type to decide which options will be rendered with the data.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. The error message says "Cannot read property 'salt' of undefined" because the **encrypted** output is "The ciphertext you get back after encryption isn't a string yet. It's a CipherParams object. A CipherParams object gives you access to all the parameters used during encryption.". So kindly share a minimal but complete example of encryption & decryption including data, key and ciphertext, thanks.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelFehr for the reply. encryption & decryption is an npm package downloaded. it take s a string does it thing and so I am use it to encrypt a string for a cookie than decrypt it as I get it. I assume it errors out because in the testing suite it doesn't actually have access to the brower cookies so the input is undefined so there is nothing to salt. I can remove that piece for the test if needed just was hoping there was a way to mock a cookie for the test to get.